# CompareTo of comparable does not take arguments other than Object type.

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

It seems odd that this is not working as I expected. I wrote a simple java class that implements Comparable interface and override the compareTo() method. However, It doesn't let me pass arguments of specific type other than Object. I looked on other guys' codes online which they did used other typed objects and I copied their code into eclipse and still I got the same error.

My question is; what I have to do to compare this object with object of type lets say Person. I do have the same issue with Comparator Interface (compare() method).

This code is the one I found it online.

```
public class Person implements Comparable {

private String name;
private int age;

public Person(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public int getAge() {
    return this.age;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "";
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Person per) {
    if(this.age == per.age)
        return 0;
    else
        return this.age > per.age ? 1 : -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person e1 = new Person("Adam", 45);
    Person e2 = new Person("Steve", 60);

    int retval = e1.compareTo(e2);
    switch(retval) {
        case -1: {
            System.out.println("The " + e2.getName() + " is older!");
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            System.out.println("The " + e1.getName() + " is older!");
            break;
        }
        default:
            System.out.println("The two persons are of the same age!");
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use **generics** to provide a specific type.

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> { // Note the generic to Person here.
    public int compareTo(Person o) {}
}
```

The `Comparable` interface is defined something like this,

```
public interface Comparable<T> {
    public int compareTo(T o);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of generics to use custom object types. Change your class definition from

```
public class Person implements Comparable {
```

to

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
```

Now you should be able to pass Person object to your `compareTo` method as mentioned here:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Person personToCompare){
```

Learn more about generics here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html